# JMeter recording iOS native application that uses HTTPS leads to SSL handshake issue

Tags: iphone, ipad, ssl, https, jmeter

I have an IPAD hybrid app for our application. It tries to hit our https server during login process. I would like to use JMeter to record this simple flow.

I am running JMeter proxy server in my local machine.  I updated IPAD proxy details so that any activity will go via JMeter proxy - so that i can record.

I am able to record in JMeter the activities i do in Safari browser of the IPAD. But if i access my app in IPAD JMeter sends it as http request & records javax.net.ssl.sslhandshakeexception error . In the browser i can accept the SSL certificate. Not sure how it can be done in IPad.

I even tried to export the certificate from my browser , sent it to my email , accessed it in IPAD and installed. Still it does not work. Looks like it is a temporary certificate issued by JMeter.

If it is not https, then JMeter will be able to record the app activities.

Anyone has faced similar situation? how did you rsolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use jmeter 2.11 with Java 7 , it creates a crt file in jmeter/bin folder.
It is the CA that creates the certificates.

Send this file by mail and open it in Ipad and install it.

In test script recorder, put in the dedicated field HTTPS domains , the domains you are trying to hit, see:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder

Restart Ipad and jmeter test script recorder and try again.