# Mobile Application Testing With Jmeter

Tags: android, performance, jmeter

In our organization we are using Proxy to connect mobile devices with Internet.
Can anyone please help to configure mobile device to work with Jmeter.

As my understanding we have to configure Jmeter Proxy into mobile device to work with,But if i ma configuring that into mobile my internet will stop working.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you will be using a test mobile device, rather than an active mobile on a real live account.

However, the Jmeter Proxy should be configured to point at your current proxy. It is inserted into a chain, rather than replacing the chain.  Therefore your mobile internet should continue to work as long as the jmeter proxy is running.

Here is the official guide to setting up Jmeter Proxy:

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf

If using a test device/account is not an option, then you will need to switch the proxy on the device whenever you want to stop testing and use the device normally.  You can probably find an app to make the switch easier.

Answer (score 0):

Your mobile devices can be configured to use JMeter proxy server. In that way you can record the HTTP requests you send to the server.

I had a similar issue. This post clarifies it.

[JMeter recording iOS native application that uses HTTPS leads to SSL handshake issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25171826/jmeter-recording-ios-native-application-that-uses-https-leads-to-ssl-handshake-i)

Answer (score 0):

I've done it successfully. For that you"ve to use **ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA** file on your device.